Spring declarative REST client with custom type in URL
I'm trying out Springs declarative REST client (with org.springframework.web.client.RestClient).
I have a wrapper:
@JvmInline
value class CustomId(val id: String)

And now I want to use that wrapper in my interface:
interface FooClient {

    @GetExchange(value = "/service/{id}")
    fun hamtaTaxeringsenhet(@PathVariable id: CustomId): Bar
}

The problem with this is that Spring converts CustomId with its toString() function and sends that to the downstream server.
If I use String instead of my custom type it works:
interface FooClient {

    @GetExchange(value = "/service/{id}")
    fun hamtaTaxeringsenhet(@PathVariable id: String): Bar
}

But I want to have type safety so I don't want to use String.
I don't want to override CustomId's toString() function either.
Any ideas how to make Spring convert CustomId to a String (CustomId.id) automatically?
Regards, Peter

By writing a converter which converts from String to CustomId and vice-versa. Yes Converter is an interface (it has multiple) which you should implement and register.

Thank you for your suggestion!
I've tried implementing converters and registering them first with @Component and then by registering them manually with WebMvcConfigurer.addFormatters(...) but they doesn't even get called when I debug the code.

You didn't accidentily add @EnableWebMvc somewhere? Are y ou using Spring Boot or plain Spring Mvc or are you using Spring WebFlux instead of mvc?

I'm using spring-boot-starter-web so Spring Boot with Spring MVC.

Of course I found the answer myself some minutes after posting the question and despite searching and trying a lot of things for a couple of hours! :D
I was setting up my FooClient without an ConversionService and now when I do it works:
@Bean
fun fooClient(restClient: RestClient, conversionService: ConversionService): FooClient {
    return HttpServiceProxyFactory
        .builderFor(RestClientAdapter.create(restClient))
        .conversionService(conversionService) // <- Added this
        .build()
        .createClient(FooClient::class.java)
}

